# Ionic 2 Fetching Data From Nested Arrays

Tags: arrays, json, angular, object, ionic2

I am new to Ionic 2 / Angular 2 and I have been trying to fix a simple issue for an app I am building but have found no solution so far.

I am simply trying to fetch data from a json file to list a number of categories (film titles) and display more detail (production details) into a detail page. The details (director and producer) are nested within an array (production) in the json file.

Although I am able to fetch the film tiles from the json file, **I am not able to accesss and display the data from the nested array once the detail page is open.**

I have tried a lot of different things (including looping through the array using for Each, creating a production object) but nothing seems to be working. Unless I am missing something very obvious?

Can someone please help?
Thanks in advance! (I will be eternally grateful for any response.)

**home.ts**

```
export class HomePage {
   films: any;
   productions: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) { 
    this.films = this.http.get("assets/data/results-data.json").map(res => res.json());
  }

  openDetails(film) {
    this.navCtrl.push('FilmDetailsPage', {film: film});
  }
}
```

**home.html**

```
<ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let film of films.results" (click)="openDetails(film)">
        {{ film.title }}
    </button>
</ion-list>
```

**results-data.json (extract)**

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "title": "A New Hope",
      "production":  [
        {
        "director" : "George Lucas",
        "producer" : "Rick McCallum"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Attack of the Clones",
      "production": [
        {
          "director": "George Lucas",
          "producer": "Kurtz"
        }
      ]
    },
```

**film-detail.html**

```
    <ion-header>
    <ion-navbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>{{ film.title }}</ion-title>  // Working
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <ion-card>
        <ion-card-content>
            **{{ production.director }} // Not working**
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

**film-detail.ts**

```
export class FilmDetailsPage {
  film: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.film = this.navParams.get('film');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this, I think there is a problem with your path:

**film-detail.html**

```
    <ion-header>
    <ion-navbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>{{ film.title }}</ion-title>  // Working
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <ion-card>
        <ion-card-content>
            {{ film.production[0].director }}
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Merci Melchia ;) this answers the issue I described above. Having said that I just realised that I didn't quite explain the real issue I am having well enough so I opened a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47403274/ionic-2-angular-2-fetching-data-from-object-within-array

Comment: I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

To make ajax request in angular

```
this.http.get("assets/data/results-data.json").subscribe(data => {
  // Read the result field from the JSON response.
  this.films = data['results'];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should try this:

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-card>
        <ion-card-content>
            {{ film.production[0]?.director }}
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

I was having the same problem but I solved my problem by using the above code. And it renders the html first so that's why error and by using the ?, it will solve the problem.