# Ionic 2 / Angular 2 Fetching Data from Object within Array

Tags: javascript, angular, object, multidimensional-array, ionic2

I am trying to build a simple accordion in `Ionic 2` by pulling data from a **json** file.
I can iterate through the category and subcategories items to list those, however once a **subcategory** is clicked, I am not able to fetch the data from the **subcategory** object and display it (subcategory title) on a detail page. I have looked at many different tutorials/forums but couldn't find how to do this anywhere.

I imagine it is not just an issue with the path but I might need to iterate through the subcategory objects further?

**json**

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "category": "Category 1",
      "subCategory": [
          {
            "title":  "subCategory 1.1",
             "word": "hello"  
          },
        {
          "title": "subCategory 1.2",
          "word": "hello"
        }
          ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Category 2",
      "subCategory": [
        {
          "title": "subCategory 2.1",
          "word": "hello"
        },
        {
          "title": "subCategory 2.2",
          "word": "hello"
        }
      ]
    }
   ]
}
```

**home.html**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>Categories</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of (items | async)?.results">
            {{ item.category }}

            <div *ngFor="let subItem of item.subCategory">
                <button (click)="openDetails(item)">{{ subItem.title }}</button>
            </div>

        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

**home.ts**

```
export class HomePage {
   items: any;
   subcategories: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) { 
    this.items = this.http.get("assets/data/results-data.json").map(res => res.json());
  }

  openDetails(item) {
    this.navCtrl.push('FilmDetailsPage', {item: item});
  }
}
```

**detail.html**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>{{ item.subCategory.title }}</ion-title> // NOT WORKING


    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: details.ts looks like an html, can you please update source to be accurate or better yet add a stackblitz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the `subItem` i.e. each subcategory and not the item to `openDetails()` function.

```
<button (click)="openDetails(subItem)">{{ subItem.title }}</button><!-- here -->
```

In your details.html,

you can access as

```
<ion-title>{{ subItem.title }}</ion-title> <!-- make sure the parameter in ts file has name subItem. -->
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Suraj. I had to use an elvis operator in the path on details.html to get it working but it definitely did the trick.

Comment: <ion-title>{{ subItem?.title }}</ion-title>